# web app dns override

Tags: scala, dns

I am not a programmer but I have an idea that I would like to see developed. I want to have a cross platform web app that is programmed to, for any DNS look-up request from any app on the device (even native apps), first look in our DNS server that will check to see if the service provider is a member of our system, and if so, a different experience will be delivered to the user, and if not, then the user's device should be forwarded to the normal DNS that is specified in system settings. Is this feasible? Are there any risks to the users or me? Can the code be safe from being tampered with?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not easily feasible for a web application. In effect what you are doing is running your own DNS server which the users connect to and if the website provider is a member you already have their DNS records loaded and it providers one set of records and if the website is not a member then it performs a forward lookup to an upstream provider to get the global DNS records for the DNS query made. I have implemented this for a number of small and medium businesses on their local networks so that queries to certain domains from the LAN resolve to internal addresses, both for the purpose of blocking domains from being accessed from work as well as for connecting the users to local servers where the domain in question is hosted locally, however to do this for client devices not on a single network would mean you would have to either install software to change the DNS settings on the device or to have the user change their DNS settings themselves which would not give you a unified experience as some would and some wouldn't, especially if you are talking about members of the public and their own devices. If memory serves there are also restrictions in place on mobile devices including Android and iOS devices which prevent an app from altering network settings such as DNS as a security precaution as such an app would present a huge risk to user online security. The best bet would be to simply provide DNS hosting for service providers and they host their DNS records with you and so you can present the enhanced experience to the end user.

Comment: OK, this is exactly the answer I needed. But - my bad - something I failed to mention is our plan to provide the same sort of enhanced experience for native apps too (including offline apps) - if there are such things nowadays at all. So we would like to have some sort of ID from the app vendor and then with our web app pre-check any offline native app against our list of IDs and determine if the vendor is a member or not before they are launched with the enhanced or normal experience. I hope you will have an equally brilliant answer for this as well.

Comment: I would have to say my original answer would have to stand even in this use case. Firstly, without jail-breaking the mobile devices there is no documented or legitimate way to intercept the startup of an app on a mobile device, in addition mobile apps are generally sandboxed to prevent interaction between them except through documented API's which would further prevent this from happening. There is also no way through the standard protocols either through the low level TCP/IP protocols, or the higher HTTP, SOCKS, etc protocols...

Comment: to pass an app ID as part of the data stream. Short of creating your own mobile device operating system to compete with iOS and android you wouldnt be able to do it.

Comment: I need a clarification from you please. If we were to host DNS for our member vendors, then when an end user's device connects to his ISP's DNS does our identity get revealed in the process of the look-up as the original/primary DNS host of that vendor? That is one way we could start small and cover the www side of the market, while we work on the competing OS. I really appreciate your input.

Comment: No the end user would not see your identity in the DNS process, the only time anyone would know you where hosting the DNS records would be if they did an authoratative check on a domain name and saw that your name servers are the authoritative sources for the DNS records.